# Leaflet cluster point with same coordinates

Tags: qgis, leaflet

i have many points with the same coordinates, for example 5 points in one location. But when i zoom cluster, it is not devided automaticaly, i have to click manualy to cluster circle. It is possible to automaticaly devided markers with the same coordinates when i zoom in ?